# kein Interesse or keine Interesse

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

When I search in google
`"habe kein Interesse an"` -> 310.000 results
`"habe keine Interesse an"` -> 6.380 results

However
`"habe groß Interesse an"` -> 50 results
`"habe große Interesse an"` -> 5.180 results

What's the reason for this inconsistency, i.e. why `kein` rather than `keine`?

Comment: Sometimes even german people cannot write down their language correctly. A significant number of typos is another source for your results.

Comment: For the sake of completeness and correctness, you should also look up "habe großes Interesse an"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I write the answer because it seems native speakers can hardly understand what problems non-native speakers have.

It is "**das** Interesse" - **neuter**, not feminine. Therefore, "kein Interesse" is correct and "keine Interesse" is not.

I remember it was a bit problem for me too, this word sounds *sooo* feminine and in my language it is feminine...

Comment: I understand the difficulty, but looking up the gender in a dictionary is still something that you should have done before asking the question, and it would not have been more effort than your Google investigation.

Comment: @CarstenS I did, but I was so sure it was feminine that I misread everytime.